# Calling functions and parameters through the code

Tags: python

I would like to write a program where I can call functions to run the code. 
I wanted to let user to choice input parameters as follows:

```
q=input("Choose a query: ")
question=input("Would you like to run the code? ")
    if question == 'y':
        e_date=s_date
        fun1(q, s_date, e_date) # to collect data
        fun2(q, s_date) # to save data into file
```

Please see below an extract of the function that I would need to run. `Fun1` collects data, in particular `links` and `titles`. In order to do this, I need a `query`, `start date` and `end date` (I add this information manually, as shown in the code above). 
`fun1` seems work fine.
The second function, `fun2`, should save data collected from fun1 into a file csv. However I am having some issues with the `append_write`, specifically:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'append_write' referenced before assignment
```

I think the problem could be also due to `links` and `titles` (maybe also in q and start date) as I do not know how to call them into `fun2` and use them through the code. 
Could you please have a look and tell me how I could fix this issue? Thanks.

```
def fun1(q,s_date,e_date):

   ...

    links = []
    titles = []

    while True:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'lxml')
        result_div = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'g'})
        time.sleep(3)
        for r in result_div:
                try:
                    link = r.find('a', href=True)
                    time.sleep(2)
                    title = None
                    title = r.find('h3')

                    if isinstance(title,Tag):
                        title = title.get_text()
                    if link != '' and title != '':
                        links.append(link['href'])
                        titles.append(title)
                except Exception as e:
                    continue
...

    return links, titles

def fun2(q,s_date):    
    f = 'path'+q+'.csv'

    if os.path.exists(f):
            res_1 = input("Append data: ")
            if res_1 == 'y':
                append_write = 'a'
                header_TF = False
            if res_1 == 'n':
                res_2 = input("Write a new file: ")
                if res_2 == 'y':
                    append_write = 'w' 
                    header_TF = True
                else: 
                    print("Wrong choice!")
    else:
        print("There was an error.\n")

    df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": s_date, "Links" : links, "Titles" : titles})
    df.to_csv(f, mode=append_write, header=header_TF, index=False)
```

The error message is related to the call `fun2(q, s_date) # to save data into file` and `df.to_csv(f, mode=append_write, header=header_TF, index=False)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'append_write' referenced before assignment
```

The error message is telling you that you're trying to use the variable `append_write` before you've assigned anything to it.  You don't provide the stack trace that says where exactly this happens, but an obvious place it might occur is in `fun2`:

```
def fun2(q,s_date):    
    f = 'path'+q+'.csv'

    if os.path.exists(f):
        res_1 = input("Append data: ")
        if res_1 == 'y':
            append_write = 'a'
            header_TF = False
        if res_1 == 'n':
            res_2 = input("Write a new file: ")
            if res_2 == 'y':
                append_write = 'w' 
                header_TF = True
            else: 
                print("Wrong choice!")
    else:
        print("There was an error.\n")

    df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": s_date, "Links" : links, "Titles" : titles})
    df.to_csv(f, mode=append_write, header=header_TF, index=False)
```

So `append_write` will never be initialized if ANY of the following are true:

1. `f` does not exist
2. `res_1` is not exactly either `'y'` or `'n'`
3. `res_1` is `'n'` but `res_2` is not exactly `'y'`

Maybe in those circumstances your code should `return` instead of trying to continue?  Or maybe you should supply a default value for `append_write`?  I'm not really sure what the function is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Sam. The relevant code is shown in the post. I included in my code the `res_1` and `res_2` `y` or `n` (in `else`), though it has not been included in the post. I think the problem might be in links and titles as I do not know if I am calling them correctly into `fun2`. `fun2` should just save their values (values that were appended in lists in `fun1`) into a `csv` file. I updated the question to show where I get the error. From `fun2` I should only get the file csv with `links` and `titles` saved there. I think the problem might be in case `f` does not exist.

Comment: It was because of the `f`. Thank you so much @Sam Stafford